# Showing a certain limit or an upper bound of it goes to zero

Tags: calculus, limits

I have the following limit which I know is equal to zero (using Mathematica soft.), however, I can't show it analytically.

$\lim_{L \rightarrow \infty} (\ln{L})^2\left[1-\left(1-e^{-\frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{L}-2)}\right)^L\right]$

I would appreciate any help.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $L\ge4$, [Bernoulli's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality) says
$$
\begin{align}
\log(L)^2\left[1-\left(1-e^{-\frac12(\sqrt{L}-2)}\right)^L\right]
&\le\log(L)^2\left[1-\left(1-Le^{-\frac12(\sqrt{L}-2)}\right)\right]\\
&=\log(L)^2Le^{-\frac12(\sqrt{L}-2)}
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $L$ is natural number

Hence  $$\lim_{L \rightarrow \infty}\ (\ln{L})^2\left[1-\left(1-L e^{-\frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{L}-2)}\right)\right] =\lim_{M\rightarrow \infty}\ M^ka^{M}=0$$ for some $0<a<1$ and some $k>1$